# Spark ML OnlineLDA Algortihm is giving OutofMemory Exception?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am implementing `OnlineLDA` algorithm of Spark ML with `Spark_Version = 2.0.2` with following properties :-

```
setK = 50 [Topics]
setmaxIterations = 10
setDocConcenration = -1
settopiConcentration = -1
```

and configurations :
`2 workers with 24Gb Memory Each with driver memory 25 GBs`
And i am running this algorithm with the corpus generated from 50k Documents
i am getting `javaHeapSpaceError` on one of the workers.

There is a parameter called 
`setMiniBatchFraction()` and i have set the value for this parameter to `0.004`

Query :- can anyone tell me about `setMiniBatchFraction()` method 
what changes i need to make to get rid of this exception

I am newbee is Spark ML any suggestions are welcome.
**Thanks in Advance**